# MySql pass url from php to database

Tags: php, mysql, url, escaping, quotes

in my `php` code, I've a sql string `select * from tablename where url in (%s)`;

I'm constructing the input array from `urls`, which is array of url strings. `$urls = array("https://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com/try002");`

I've tried multiple ways but no luck.

Method 1:

```
$inputParams = array(implode(", ", $urls));
```

this gives me error of `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://www.example.com,https://www.example.com/photos/try002)'`

Method 2:
So I tried to add both double and single escape quotes, because when I try in sql db, `select * from tablename where url in ("https://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com/blabla")` works.

```
foreach($urls as &$url)
{
   $url = "'" . urlencode($url) . "', ";
}
$inputParams = array($urls);
```

Neither of double or single quotes worked. It produces query of `select * from tablename where url in (`\"https://example.com\", `"www.example.com/blabla")`

How should I formulate my input urls so that I can get something like 
`select * from tablename where url in ("https://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com/blabla")` please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: You're not quoting or escaping the values properly. Just use placeholder values and bind and your problem's solved.

Comment: You should use prepared statements but in the interim changing `$inputParams = array(implode(", ", $urls));` to `$inputParams = "'" . array(implode("', '", $urls)). "'";` should work